# web console in chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

In Firefox, there is a Web Console accessible through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>.

The Firefox Web Console can show us stuff like:

> [15:06:32.190] GET asd.com [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 330ms]

Is there a similar Web Console in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chrome console (SHIFT-CTRL - I) does show stuff like that. There is also a Chrome extension to get firebug in Chrome (its a light version)

when you press SHIFT CTRL I click on the console tab and thats where it will be shown. You might need to right click and check the "XMLHttpRequest Loggin" to view all logs

Comment: Or F12 if you prefer a single keystroke rather than ctrl-shift-I.

Answer (score 3):

SHIFT - CTRL - I

SHIFT - CTRL - J

Shows you the developer tools and the javascript console, respectively.

Comment: i mean the firefox web console not the js console. the firefox web console can show us stuff like **[15:06:32.190] GET http://www.asd.com/ [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 330ms]**